# How to change username limit on MySQL

Tags: mysql

By default MySQL limits usernames to only 16 characters.
For my project I need a username composed of 3 components each up to 20 characters long,
so I will need to increase the limit to 64 characters (including separators).

What settings do I need to change?

Comment: `MySQL user names are up to 32 characters long` .https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-names.html . Read carefully the `Warning` section

Comment: Depends on the version you're running. If it's earlier than 5.7, you're stuck at 16 char, otherwise 32 char.

Comment: You cannot change user account name length with a configuration setting. You need to modify mysql's source code and recompile it.